# FFMPEG Not Accepting Set Variable %~n1

Tags: ffmpeg, video, syntax

The script is to process images named `Image1.png` thru `Image10.png`. The images are resized then the resized image is converted to video with same file name with extension `mp4`.

Please consider the following script:

```
FOR %%G IN (Image*.png) DO (


ffmpeg -i %%G -vf scale=4096:-1 -y out.png

Set "FF=%~n1"
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i out.png -c:v libx264 -t 1 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y %FF%.mp4


del out.png
)
```

The result from this script is:

1. Each Image file is resized and written to file `out.png` in turn.
2. File `out.png` is deleted at the end of session.
3. The video created is `MP4.mp4` which is from the last `.png` file being `Image9.png`

Why is variable %FF% which is %~n1 not being passed through FFMPEG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for extracting the file-name part without extension or path
for the loop variable of the FOR command is as follows:

```
Set FF=%%~nG
```

You need two percent characters inside the loop, rather than one,
and the variable is `G` and not `1` (which is the notation for
the first argument of a script).

Another problem is that you need
[EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
for  variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at
parse time.

This is my test script that demonstrates these points
that you can use as a model :

```
%echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%G IN (*.png) DO (
  rem echo %%G : %%~nG
  Set FF=%%~nG
  echo !FF!
)
```

Comment: Changing the script as you recommend result is is similar to before only one MP4 file created and it is for 'Goggle9.png". For diagnostics I added the line "Echo %FF% > hh.txt" and the file contain    ECHO is on.

Comment: Will look at it tomorrow.

Comment: I see that the problem is with my ffmpeg script to create the MP4. It appears that %FF% is returning nothing within the ffmpeg script. Here is what was display within the CMD Window:

Comment: C:\Users\xxxxx\Pictures\Saved Pictures>FOR %G IN (Goggles*.png) DO (
ffmpeg -i %G -vf scale=4096:-1 -y out.png
 Set "FF=%~nG"
 ffmpeg -loop 1 -i out.png -c:v libx264 -t 1 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y .mp4
 del out.png
)

C:\Users\xxxxx\Pictures\Saved Pictures>(
ffmpeg -i Goggles1.png -vf scale=4096:-1 -y out.png
 Set "FF=Goggles1"
 ffmpeg -loop 1 -i out.png -c:v libx264 -t 1 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y .mp4
 del out.png
)

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax issue about `Set FF=%%~nG` is resolved.

But the second problem is not resolve and will be resubmitted to the group.

The script `%FF%.mp4` fails to pass which is in:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i out.png -c:v libx264 -t 1 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y %FF%.mp4
```